# Continue game on another PS4

Tags: ps4, ps-remote-play

I own two PS4s, one in the family room and another in a 2nd room where I exercise on a treadmill. Is there any way I can pause (not quit) a game on the family room PS4 and go to the treadmill and continue the game paused on the main PS4, using the 2nd PS4 and its TV and controller?

I don't want to have to save to the cloud or a USB stick and copy it to the second PS4 to do this.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, I strongly suspect this wouldn't be possible. But I don't own a PS4, so maybe they've got some sort of way that I'm not aware of. :)

Comment: Note for general reference: playing an action game while walking on a treadmill is not easy. Or rather, it is an easy way to get hurt. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is PS4 to PS4 remote play and this is not possible. There is a solution though. While it didn't get much love, the PlayStation TV will allow you to do exactly what you want to do.

The PlayStation TV is pretty a PS Vita but it plugs into your TV. It supports remote play just like the vita does. This means you can pause your game on the main PS4 and move over to your other room where PS TV is setup, trigger remote play and you are good to go.

The PlayStation/Vita TV costs like $50 so it's a cheaper alternative to owning 2 PS4s.

Answer (score 2):

There really aren't many choices on this. The best way to actually to do what you are wanting to accomplish is via usb/cloud transfer files between PlayStations. The only way to do it without transferring saves is to have one PlayStation hooked up to two different tv's (which isn't desirable unless you have really long cords on hand!)

Answer (score 1):

No, because everything that's going on with the PS4 in one room is stored in that machine's memory and cannot be transferred to another console.

You don't say if the game is on a Blu-Ray but if it is, then you wouldn't even be able to start the game on the second console without the disc.

Two options that I can see:-

1. Save in the cloud or USB stick and transfer the save.
2. Get an HDMI splitter and run the cable from one PS4 into both TV's.

The second option would only work if the TV's are close to each other, both in terms of the picture quality / resolution loss over long distances of HDMI cables and in how far the Bluetooth of the PS4 controller will reach.

Comment: All the reasons you point are are why I don't want to run the game on the second PS4 - I just want to "send the screen" aka "remote control" it.

Comment: @user9999999 Have you considered a HDMI video sender?

Comment: the joystick range would still be an issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is information on the various possibilities I found and tried, and their most obvious pros and cons. To summarize, the best solution is the PlayStation TV (about $60 on eBay).

**Share Play** - **PROS:** works between any two PS4s. **CONS:** requires starting a share on 1st console, accepting on the 2nd console, then going back to 1st PS4 to give away control, before using on the 2nd console. Requires two different PS accounts, and **both** must have *PlayStation Plus*.

**PS4 Remote Play on PC** - **PROS:** can use any PC. Allows taking control of existing game at any time, and taking back control at any time. Can start with PS4 off. Joystick can be connected to PC with a USB cable or with wireless adapter. **CONS:** Need a reasonable power PC that can be used for this.

**PS Vita** - **PROS:** Allows taking control of existing game at any time, and taking back control at any time. Can start with PS4 off. **CONS:** joysticks very different. Tiny screen.

**PlayStation TV** - **PROS:** Allows taking control of existing game at any time, and taking back control at any time. Can start with PS4 off. Uses standard PS4 joystick (USB cable not required). **CONS:** another device to purchase.

Comment: As for PS4 Remote Play on PC, you can now use the Dualshock USB wireless adapter https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/accessories/gaming-controllers/dualshock-4-usb-wireless-adaptor/